# Master Details using jQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, master-detail

I am trying to implement a master details solution using the jQuery Tabs. Two tabs, first tab contains Northwind Customers, selecting customer command should display tab2 with the orders for the customer.

So far, I have come to the conclusion that it cannot be done without using some sort of Ajax. **Am I correct?**

I got some pointers from Matt, [Matt Berseth](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/06/masterdetail_with_the_gridview_1.html).

**Does anyone have any idea or samples they can share on how to accomplish this?**

I am thinking that one way of doing it is to pass the CustomerId in the Client Click event of the LinkButton of GridView1 and then focus Tab2 and somehow load the details grid via javascript. I am not too good with Javascript, so I am stuck here.

Suggestions and sample code will be very helpful.

Thanks

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Customers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Orders</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" PageSize="20">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSelect" runat="server" 
Text="Select Link" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" 
        SortExpression="CustomerID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
        SortExpression="CompanyName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region" 
        SortExpression="Region" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode" 
        SortExpression="PostalCode" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="OrderID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="OrderID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="OrderID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" 
                SortExpression="CustomerID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="OrderDate" 
                SortExpression="OrderDate" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [CompanyName], [Region], [PostalCode] 
FROM [Customers]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [OrderID], [CustomerID], [OrderDate] 
FROM [Orders] WHERE ([CustomerID] = @CustomerID)">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="CustomerID" 
        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its definately doable using jQuery and AJAX and could be very nice, it will take some significant work, since you can't really use the GridView (unless you use an UpdatePanel).  What you can do is set the selected tab after postback.  There is an option on the tab control

```
$('#tabs').tabs({selected:1});
```

or

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
```

Post a comment if your interested in doing the jquery AJAX route, I can provide a sample.  Can you use a WCF Service to access your order details?

### Sample Code

I just finished some sample code based for this I uploaded it to my MS Live SkyDrive.  You will need the WCF REST Starter Kit.  [jQuery-AjaxTabsView-Sample.zip](http://cid-473151cb8afe66ba.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/jQuery-AjaxTabView-Sample.zip)

### Blog Post

I also wrote blog post describing the sample.  Thanks for the idea.  http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/jquery-tab-view-using-ajax-and-wcf-rest-service/

Comment: bendewey, thanks for you response. I would like to see the sample of the jQuery Ajax option. I am thinking this would be the only route to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need AJAX since the JQuery tabs don't post back to the server.  If you want tabbed behaviour that *does* post back, its fairly easy to [implement manually](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/TabControl.aspx), or you can download a wide assortment of pre-built controls for this.

If there is a particular reason to want to use the JQuery tabs, [here is an example](http://kuujinbo.info/ajax/jq_tabs.aspx) of it being used with AJAX fragments.  You'll probably want to wire up your click events from the grid in your master list to both load the ajax content into the 2nd tab, as well as switch to the tab automatically as part of the ajax callback.

Comment: Soviut, Thanks for the response. No particular reason for using jQuery other than it might me faster and lighter than AjaxToolKit. I am always open to suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: It seems like you're not even sure you want to use AJAX, so why default to *any* client side framework or ajax kit?